# How to insert and shift elements in array in ASM?

Tags: arrays, assembly, array-push, mov

I'm currently assigned with a project to make a very basic text editor. Insert, backspace, etc. I'm having trouble trying to implement insert.

I already covered having the text print correctly to video memory (B800), and I'm able to calculate the location in the buffer of a letter selected by the cursor.

So for example, if I had the word Apple printed and my cursor is currently under the 'A', I want to insert to the right.

So I feel as if I'm missing something in my notes from class, but basically we learned to start shifting from the end of the buffer to the "right", so we can end up with "A pple", the space being the new spot for the new character.

But I'm confused on the approach. It seems we are to use MOVSB
Si being the last char to copy, Di where it should go and Cx being the amount of characters.

So in "Apple", Si would be set to the first p, Di would be +1 to the right of that? For CX, that would be 4 I assume? Since we have to shift 4 over

But I also have noted since we are using video memory, using MOVSB the way it is would not be good since ES is set to B800. I have written down "this instead", but it seems to be the same thing as MOVSB works, so I'm not sure if I wrote something down wrong or I'm missing something.

Also I generally don't see why we are  using MOVSB, since it's just copying to a new area in memory, not really affecting what I have in my buffer array already. Any help would be appreciated :)

This is being done in 16 bit mode and I'm using emu8086

Comment: _"So in "Apple", Si would be set to the first p, Di would be +1 to the right of that?"_ Sounds like you should be copying starting from the end of the array. That is, initialize `SI` to point to the `'e'` and `DI` to point one byte beyond that, and set the direction flag `STD`.

Comment: _"it's just copying to a new area in memory, not really affecting what I have in my buffer array already"_ But if both the source and dest is within your array, then you _are_ affecting the array.

Comment: So then CX=4, the difference from the end to where I want to insert and STD since that moves the direction right to left. 
Also again, wouldn't movsb not be editing my buffer array and just be editing what's in video memory?

Comment: _"wouldn't movsb not be editing my buffer array and just be editing what's in video memory"_ That depends entirely on what you set `SI`, `DI`, `DS` and `ES` to. `REP MOVSB` will copy `CX` bytes starting at `DS:SI` to `ES:DI` (in the direction given by the direction flag).

Comment: But isn't it ES:[DI]=DS:[SI]
So B800:DI = 0700:SI, if I change ES wouldn't that crash the program?

Comment: The values of the segment registers aren't fixed. You can change them.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea why I thought that would crash the program. So after I shift, I can just set ES back to B800 to write to it I assume, thanks! :)

Comment: take care of the direction you copy. let's assume an array a[10]. if you want to "insert" a new value into a[5], you need to start at the last element working back to the first ones (a[9]=a[8], a[8]=a[7] etc), to not end up having all values starting from a[6] have the same value ( a[6]=a[5], a[7]=a[6], a[8]=a[7] ... will fail!)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I will start from the back like you said to avoid that. Thanks :)